# The Wide Vs Tall Table - benefits of each

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to create a table for UserPreferences.  There is a finite set of user preferences for each user. So this could be modeled in two ways:

1. A wide table: UserPreferenceByUser(id int, userid int, preference1 int,
   preference2 int)
2. A tall table: UserPreferenceByCode(id int, userid int, code nvarchar(25),
       value int)

The speed factor is not important as they will be retrieved once at the start of the app.

The pros/cons of 1:

- On the client, one object holds all preferences. (Easier to use on the client)
- However, every time a preference is added, then the table must be modified and the app updated.
- The default preference value can be put in the default value
  of the field.

The pros/cons of 2:

- On the client, an array holds on the preferences. (More difficult to use)
- No data model changes necessary if a new preference is added. However, when new users are added, there are no default preferences.
- If a preference is looked up and not found, a new record must be added, looking up what the default preference value is in another table (DefaultUserPreferences).

Am I missing any pros or cons in the above?

It seems to me in looking this over the ideal solution would be storing the data as UserPreferenceByCode, but then returning a pivoted set of data so it appears on the client as UserPreferenceByUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definitely missing some considerations and have some wrong.

> However, when new users are added, there are no default preferences.

This is incorrect.  Default preferences are not as simple as a `default` constraint, but they could be added using a trigger, `default` with a `case` expression, or more commonly as a "default" user.  In fact, this can be an advantage because the defaults could vary depending on other characteristics of the user, such as language or role.

You are also missing some important considerations:

- Wide tables are often smaller (because the key is not repeated), especially if the preferences are not sparse.
- Narrow tables tend to require that the preferences all have the same type.
- Narrow tables allow you to maintain additional information, such as the date the preference was changed.

The last two considerations -- along with the capability to add new preferences easily -- are often quite important in deciding which method to use.

In some cases, I have used hybrid approaches where the initial preferences are stored in columns and additional preferences are either in a separate table or even in a JSON/XML column.

Comment: Great suggestion on the JSON - I had not considered that before.